# Create the equivalent of np.meshgrid using for loops

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

This code outputs a plot of e^(-r^2) on a 2-D x,y grid :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1d = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.006)
y1d = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.006)

x2d, y2d = np.meshgrid(x1d, y1d)
r2d = x2d**2 + y2d**2

z = np.exp(-r2d)

plt.imshow(z, extent = (3, -3 , 3 , -3))
plt.title("A 2-D Image plot")
plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis')
plt.savefig('2dexp_array.pdf', format ='pdf')
plt.show(block = False)
```

I want to change the code so that instead of using np.meshgrid , it uses for loops to generate the 2d grid space.

Something like :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1d = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.006)
y1d = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.006)

z = np.zeros([2000, 2000])
```

and then using for loops to replace the zeros in z with the correct values according to x1d , y1d.

But I'm not sure how to use a for loop to mirror the function of meshgrid.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it
Thanks

Comment: Hi ! Why are you trying to generate grid space using loops?

Comment: Why are you trying to use loops to generate grids? it will be ~80 times slower with your example.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
for i,x in enumerate(x1d):
    for j,y in enumerate(y1d):
        z[i,j] = np.exp(-(x**2 + y**2))
```

Comment: shouldn't it be z[len(x1d)-i,len(y1d)-j] ?